# Graphql query to get an object nested in multiple layers

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, querying

I am a graphql noob and the first query I have to write turned to be a complex one. Imagine this is the object I'm looking for

```
{
  name : "ferrari"
  year : "1995"
}
```

Now, there is a nested object in which this could be present, The object could look like this

```
{
  "name": "car",
  "year": "1990",
  "morecars": [
    {
      "name": "ferrari",
      "year": "1995"
    },
    {
      "name": "bmw",
      "year": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

or this

```
{
  "name": "car",
  "year": "1990",
  "morecars": [
    {
      "name": "red",
      "year": "1990",
      "morecares": [
        {
          "name": "ferrari",
          "year": "1995"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "bmw",
      "year": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do fetch the `ferrari` i need

Comment: graphql is not for finding it for you (filtering is an API role) - it can return any of this structures - type can be used recurently - normalizing cache (apollo client) can store each item separately